# How to get inner text in html under "id"

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

i am trying this. I am stuck for my project please help to bring this specific point under "id".

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetlastPrice()
Dim ws As Worksheet, re As Object, p As String, r As String, URL As String

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
p = """tradedVolume"":""(.*?)"""
Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

URL = "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuote.jsp?symbol=PEL"
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", URL, False
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .send
        If .Status = 200 Then
            r = GetValue(re, .responseText, p)
        Else
            r = "Failed connection"
        End If
End With
ws.Range("B2").Value = r


End Sub

Public Function GetValue(ByVal re As Object, ByVal inputString As String, ByVal pattern As String) As String
With re
    .Global = True
    .pattern = pattern
    If .test(inputString) Then  ' returns True if the regex pattern can be matched agaist the provided string
        GetValue = .Execute(inputString)(0).submatches(0)
    Else
        GetValue = "Not found"
    End If
End With
End Function
```

The marked value i want in my excel sheet

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in different ways. Turn out that you look for the wrong key to get it's value. The right key here is `totalTradedVolume`.

One way:

```
Sub GetPrice()
    Const URL = "https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuote.jsp?symbol=PEL"
    Dim Html As New HTMLDocument, elem$, price$

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    elem = Html.querySelector("#responseDiv").innerText
    price = Split(Split(elem, "totalTradedVolume"":""")(1), """,")(0)

    MsgBox price

End Sub
```

If you stick to the way you have tried already, bring about this small change within it:

```
p = """totalTradedVolume"":""(.*?)"""
```

Comment: If the problem you were facing is solved, make sure to tick the grayed out checkmark next to my answer to accept it as a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Hello. When testing the code, I got Access denied. Is that related to some restrictions on the url. Although when navigating to the url, it works with no problems.

Comment: The requested url is different now. Try the modified one. It should work.